# Cannot generate new project using yeoman generator Gradle+Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, yeoman-generator

I installed Android Studio on Mac using `brew install Caskroom/cask/android-studio`

Then, I run `yo gradle-kotlin`, and got the following error. What can I do to make my first Hello World work?

Thank you

```
✔ /Volumes/Git/android/kotlin-hello-world 
10:53 $ yo gradle-kotlin

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |      Welcome to the      |
   `---------´   | incredible Gradle+Kotlin |
    ( _´U`_ )    |        generator!        |
    /___A___\    '--------------------------'
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

  Detecting installed Gradle version...
  Fetching latest Kotlin version from Maven Central...
✔ Fetched latest Kotlin version: 1.0.1-2
✔ Detected installed Gradle version: 2.12
? What's your project name? kotlin hello world
? What Gradle version would you like to use? 2.12
? What Kotlin version would you like to use? 1.0.1-2
? Do you want to use Kotlin Reflection? Yes
? Would you like to use IDEA Gradle plugin? Yes
identical .gitignore
identical src/main/kotlin/.gitkeep
identical src/test/kotlin/.gitkeep
identical build.gradle
identical gradle.properties
identical settings.gradle
  Executing 'gradle wrapper' command...

✔ Done executing 'gradle wrapper' command.
  Executing Gradle tasks: idea build
internal/child_process.js:298
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
  at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
  at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
  at Function.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-gradle-kotlin/node_modules/cross-spawn-async/index.js:13:18)
  at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-gradle-kotlin/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:34:23)
  at GradleKotlinGenerator.spawnCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-gradle-kotlin/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/spawn_command.js:20:10)
  at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-gradle-kotlin/generators/app/gradle-kotlin.coffee:78:8)
  at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

Comment: Do you have jre/jdk installed on your machine?

Comment: yes, I installed java via
    brew install ant
    brew install maven
    brew install gradle
    brew install android-sdk
    brew install android-ndk
    brew cask install java

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed it.

It was an OSX-specific bug in the generator logic, a rather stupid one: it incorrectly detected the platform and tried to call `./gradlew.bat`, it didn't even realize it's a .bat file, the reason for EACCES error actually was that this .bat didn't have +x permission. Just update the generator to 1.1.1 and it should be fine.